# batch programming

Tags: batch-file

I am new in batch. Trying for some days to make something in batch but have a problem I cannot solve. I read a lot of your comments but did not find answer. Maybe you can help me?

The point is:

1. I input string from keyboard( e.g. 10 characters ). name of it is"allinputstring"
2. Calculate of length is ok ( by redirect in txt file and expand its bytes ). name "length"
3. Parse string in 10 pieces (strings) is ok.

So here is a problem, I want to echo these pieces, so I use next code, I use a counter to find out is the counter give me good count as output variable, and echo it to see on screen if it is good. Counter seems good, end echo of pieces strings is good enough. But I want to put in line 5. Variable `count` instead of `"%%m"`, and cannot find a syntax way how to do it.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%m in (1,1,!lenght!) do (
  set /a count=0
  set /a count=count+%%m
  echo !count!!allinputstring:~%%m,1!
)
endlocal
```

please help me.

Comment: lenght is mis-spelled

Comment: I made an edit and put %count% in :)

Comment: so, is it a way to change variable %%m with count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@ECHO off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET allinputstring=abcdefghijk
SET lenght=10
for /l %%m in (1,1,!lenght!) do (
  set /a count=0
  set /a count=count+%%m
  FOR %%z IN (!count!) DO echo !count! !allinputstring:~%%z,1!
)
GOTO :eof
```

Does this do what you require?

---

So... to make COUNT show (I've assigned it to KOWNT, but the syntax `endlocal&set count=%count%` would assign it to `COUNT` instead)

I've changed the starting value of the `FOR/L` because character counting starts from character#0 in the string.

```
@ECHO off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET allinputstring=abcdefghij
SET lenght=9
for /l %%m in (0,1,!lenght!) do (
  set /a count=0
  set /a count=count+%%m
  FOR %%z IN (!count!) DO echo !count! !allinputstring:~%%z,1!
)
endlocal&SET KOWNT=%count%
ECHO Now KOWNT=%KOWNT% but count=%count% because we have exited the SETLOCAL
GOTO :eof
```

When the `ENDLOCAL` is encountered, the parser substitutes the CURRENT value of the variables in the line and **THEN** executes the line.

Hence, the line is executed as

```
endlocal&set KOWNT=9
```

since the value of `count` at the time is 9.

When the `SETLOCAL` is executed, all changes to the environment since the matching `SETLOCAL` are thrown away. The environment variables are restored to their state when the `SETLOCAL` was executed and `count` becomes empty again (as it was before the routine.) **THEN** the `SET` instruction is executed, which sets `KOWNT` to 9.

Comment: i was trying to find a way how to make this, but after finished, variable count must stay with last value in her. endoro makes good with command call, but i dont understand logic of call in that line. and one more thing: count is e.g. 1-10, but last character is not on screen. i know why, but dont find a way how to make him show??

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a lenght=9
set "allinputstring=ABCDEFGHIJ"
for /l %%m in (0,1,%lenght%) do (
  set /a count=0
  set /a count+=%%m
  echo !count! !allinputstring:~%%m,1!
)
endlocal
```

Output is:

```
0 A
1 B
2 C
3 D
4 E
5 F
6 G
7 H
8 I
9 J
```

Comment: this is ok, but on that way i dont have variable to work with later, because %%m dissapear after for is finished, if iam right?

Comment: %%m disappear after the parentheses `)` You can work with %count% instead.

Comment: you did just as i am, but that was not what i trying to ask:)

Comment: You can't set the value of %%m, this value is set from the for loop. Inside the for loop you must use !count!, outside you can use %count%.

Comment: as much times as is value of variable length

Comment: so, how can i set counter with %%M, as you see i set it

Comment: i know !count!, but i can not find good syntaks, always is error

Comment: `set /a count=!count!+%%m` or as I did `set /a count+=%%m`, this is the same!

Comment: i cannot write echo !count! !allinputstring:~!counter!,1!

Comment: No, you can't. Write `call echo !count! %%allinputstring:~!count!,1%%`.

Comment: Hmmm, don't know. I think there is a kind of checkbox (answered) or up-arrow?

Comment: i find only unanswered in the top. but you answer this problematic syntaks. i was wondering why you put call command in front???